# Setting a grails app environment in heroku?

Tags: grails, heroku, environment

Heroku supports non-prod environments, but their documentation is sparse on the topic. They mention setting RACK_ENV for rails apps. What is the equivalent for grails?

Comment: Nope, ended up going with a different host.

Comment: I am also looking for this at the moment. The *normal* way of doing it with grails is via the `grails.env` system property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build war file first with proper environment and then upload as war file.